# Get Twilio Chat User Channels sorted by an attribute, category or tag name

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Hello I am a junior front end dev working on a volunteer project which uses Twilio chat.

I need to sort the channels we have in order based on whether they are an "Area" or "Lifestyle" i.e I would like to categorise my chat channels.

When I look at what I get back from the Twilio API when I create a channel I can see that each channel/chat room only has the key of `id` and `name`.
For example:

```
chatRooms: [{id: "bae96", name: "public"}, {id: "b7144", name: "shopping"}, {id: "59d97", name: "restaurants"},…]
0: {id: "bae96", name: "public"}
1: {id: "b7144", name: "shopping"}
2: {id: "59d97", name: "restaurants"}
```

In order for me to sort the channels i would need more information i.e another key such as `tagName` or `category` in order for the user to be able to add each channel to a `category` on creation.

e.g.
   `0: {id: "bae96", name: "shopping", category: lifestyle}`

Is this possible? How would I go about this? I saw in the documentation that it is possible to add `attributes` https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/rest/channel-resource

However i am unsure about how to do this. Is this more of a back end developer job?
Thanks in advance...